# Consumer key and Consumer secret keys from magento

Tags: magento-1.7

if i lost magento consumer key and consumer secret from magento installation then how to get these keys from magento.
I have lost these keys got after magento installation.[enter link description here](http://php-school.com/)

Comment: To which functionality these keys belongs to? Are the keys belong to Facebook, Google connect or anyother application???

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

In admin panel, System->Webservices->REST-OAuth Customers. Click on **Add New** button. There you can see the **Key and Secret** values automatically generated by Magento. You have to just add the **Customer Name**, **CALL BACK URL AND REJECTED CALL BACK URL** fields.

Comment: Happy to see that it worked for you. If it works, accept the answer and make a up vote for the answer. so that it will be helpful to other also.